# Is this code correct to post strings from Xcode and post them to a mysql database using php

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode

I am trying to use Xcode textfields to post onto my mysql server. The issue is that i don't get errors in Xcode or php but the post never gets inserted into my mysql table. I know the url is right as well as the username and password and dbname etc. Here is my code when the submit button is pressed in Xcode:

```
NSString * post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"message=test&name=%@", name.text];
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Upload.php"]]]
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];

if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
```

my php looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Johnny
JUL, 2011
*/
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "test";
    $DB_User = "root";
    $DB_Pass = "root";
    $DB_Table = "test";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO Locations('name','message') VALUES('$name','$message')";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Is there a way to test if my php file connects to my database?

Comment: There are plenty of free http request testing tools available. If you happen to be a google Chrome user, search for REST client in the chrome webstore. On a side note, I'd strongly recommend replacing your MYSQL query by a parameterized query (google it) as your current code is very susceptible to SQL Injection (google that too).

Answer (score 0):

This is some old code we use. (We have since updated to SQL Injection Prevention Techniques which I HIGHLY recommend you do!) Their are some differences I'm not 100% sure if that would fix your problem, but this code works.

Your problem may be your connection, I have never connected to a local DB server. Ive always had a DNS setup. We host through a website hosing company for our testing web service. So I have never done the http:// localhost:8888/ before and that may be where your problem lies.

I would try this first:

Try to connect to the web server (not the database) with your app and make sure you can actually connect. If you can connect then I would try my code below (double check that it properly updated your information in it). If that still doesn't work I would manually enter some data into your database and try and load it using SQL SELECT statement. If you don't have code for this message me and I can show you how to load data from a SQL Server parsing through JSON. (Sounds worse than it is.)

Once you get it up and running I would look into SQL Injection and updating your PHP to prevent it. SQL Injection prevention is not my area of expertise, but I would at least use PHP mysqli with prepared statements to protect your databases. Just google around a bit about SQL Injection Prevention.

Objective-C

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=test&name=%@", name.text];
NSString *removeSpaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
const char *urlUTF8 = [removeSpaces UTF8String];
NSString *postBody = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlUTF8];

NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postDataLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“http://localhost:8888/Upload.php“]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

PHP

```
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "dbname";  //Depending on your server setup you may need to use  'sqlname_dbname'
$DB_User = "username";  //Depending on your server setup you may need to use  'sqlname_username'
$DB_Pass = "password";  //Depending on your server setup you may need to use  'sqlname_password'


$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

if (isset ($_POST["name"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
} else {
    $name = "N/A";
}
    //
    if (isset ($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
} else {
    $message = "N/A";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Locations ('name','message') VALUES ('$name','$message') ";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

--Mike